# Is 'will' always volitional, and if not, how can we distinguish action verbs as volitional or non-volitional?

Tags: words

Etymologically, will as a verb means: "to wish, desire; be willing; be used to; be about to" (past tense wolde), from Proto-Germanic *willjan (source also of Old Saxon willian, Old Norse vilja, Old Frisian willa, Dutch willen, Old High German wellan, German wollen, Gothic wiljan "to will, wish, desire," Gothic waljan "to choose"). [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=will)

As a noun, will means: Old English will, willa "mind, determination, purpose; desire, wish, request; joy, delight," from Proto-Germanic *wiljon- (source also of Old Saxon willio, Old Norse vili, Old Frisian willa, Dutch wil, Old High German willio, German Wille, Gothic wilja "will"), related to *willan "to wish" (see will (v.1)). [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/will#etymonline_v_8011)

Therefore, I use the verb to recognize *the command or motion of choosing*, and the noun to recognize *the object that wills*.  But all of that is essentially volitional.  For example, "I will go to the grocery store," means I volunteer to go to the grocery store.  But if all of that is true, then:

- why do we commonly use 'will' to mean something that is naturally
  determined, like, "the earth will rotate on it's axis?"  The earth
  can not choose, want or wish.
- I can plan to go to the grocery store, or commit to going, but will seems more existential, if it means choose.
- If 'will' only means intent, then why do we consider someone a liar
  if they "don't actually go to the grocery store?"

As a psychologist, my work requires distinguishing between volitional and non-volitional behavior, and I've recently discovered how commonly we use 'will' for anything that we believe is going to happen in the future, instead of what I believe 'will' truly means, to 'choose'...or at a minimum, 'want.'

Any words, affixes or syntax associated with volitional or will is appreciated, including ways other languages effectively address the distinction between volitional/willful and involuntary/naturally.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about usage in a specific language (in this case English) and not linguistics (the scientific study of language). It would likely be better suited to the English site

Comment: “Will” + infinitive is used when we make a prediction which is only a guess or an opinion of ours, as in ‘He will not pass the exam’. Where's this kind of “will” in your volition story? Note, it can have subjects other than “I”, and even inanimate subjects which have no natural will, as in “The building will collapse soon”.

Comment: @Tristan i've modified the question--I don't care what language, as the last statement implied.

Comment: @YellowSky where do you get the meaning 'prediction?'  While I fully understand 'how' it is often used (as you have described), I'm relying on it's original meaning.  As for the volitional story, you can see that in the etymology shared, to "choose" as a verb, and "mind" as a noun.  However, now we know choosing only takes place in the mind, it is not the mind that actually chooses, it is the will (noun), the object that chooses.  That coherently completes the foundation of the lexeme, the way I understand it.

Comment: Hi Christopher: I think all the uses are explained here by the British Council https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/will-would

Comment: @Lambie thank you for the exhaustive list of meanings associated with 'will,' which illustrates how imprecise language can be when a single word has so many contextual meanings, requiring contextual interpretation...and why this is a linguistic and not English question.  The concept of volition is core to human existence and I'm guessing some language has not only recognized that, but also efficiently and effectively conveys it, unlike English...unless English has and I'm not aware.  The vast majority of language can be romantic, but it seems the core meanings should be systematically precise.

Comment: Christopher: Sorry but that is just not so. Every speaking subject (has their own way) of expressing themselves. And as a psychologist, that is really important to recognize. Only the listener can try and understand what the person means  and then ask when it's unclear to that listeners but human language is not written in stone at all. Precision is not a characteristic of speech...You will open the window for me, won't you? That is not volition.

Comment: @Lambie yes, of course that is true, for those who choose to embrace it.  But lawyers, accountants and scientists don't agree when it comes to the precision required in their professions.  When 'close enough' is good enough, highly precise is not required, and that applies with most people most if not almost all the time.  But the more precise we can be,  when we want to be, the better.  I agree that listeners are responsible for understanding what speakers attempt to convey, but speakers can be more responsible too...and linguists can help them both by fostering one definition per word.

Comment: No, fostering one definition per word is a fool's errand, I'm sorry. As an interpreter/translator of texts across a wide range of subjects (except physics. chemistry and math), there is specific usage in professions, yes, but I would expect a psychologist to have  less stentorian view of how natural language works and real speech by real speakers. Which includes dialects, register, formality, types of speech, dialogue, etc. The use of "will" will not necessarily help you distinguish volitional and non-volitional **behavior**.  Your attempt at philosophizing "will" seems a dead end to me. :)

Comment: [cont'd] By that I mean, a person may not have meant to kill but did kill. And it certainly is not the precision of that person's speech which will reveal it. Discourse (speech) analysis is in itself a separate endeavor and I find it loathsome to equate speech and behavior.

Comment: @Lambie speech doesn't reveal anything but what a person says.  Words however are also used in thought, and the more precisely we think, the more coherent our thoughts/understanding can be.  *I can go to the store* and *I will go to the store* mean two entirely different things, and so does *I plan to go..., I want to go..., and I hope to go....*  They don't reveal anything but what *I say* I'm feeling/thinking, but my mind knows the difference, and when my speech doesn't match my thoughts, conflict exists, becomes stress, and eventually guilt...and worse.

Comment: What people say is the whole point of many of life's aspects. Yes, those utterances mean different things, sure. I am not sure one's mind knows the difference between what one is thinking and saying, generally. People to do go around engaging in meta-cognition *ordinarily*. I think  you are confusing thinking and speaking. In short, I think you are naively moralistic and reductionist and your yearning for precision would work best in lexicography. Magritte: Ceci n'est pas une pipe.

Comment: @Lambie you are correct, the question is more about the lexeme and it's fundamental meaning, but it reaches beyond that in regard to asking how languages express willful OR natural verbs. Most speech is natural/automatic, not thoughtful, as you suggest. But what's programmed that becomes natural speech can be thought, and the more precise, the more precise our personal lexicons become. It's not a chicken and egg issue, its a garbage-in-garbage-out, or precision-in-precision-out; it always begins with in, and that is what we're pursuing, a better in when it comes to volitional verbs.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer is no. A dropped object will fall to the ground even if it has no volition of its own. All mortal beings will die whether they want to or not.

"Will" *comes from* a word meaning volition or intent, but it no longer means that in modern English. All it conveys now is future tense. Changes like this are very common in language; "really" no longer requires something to be "real", and "have" with a verb ("have eaten") no longer requires something to be held in your hands.

The linguistic term for this is *grammaticalization*, or *semantic bleaching*. The semantics of this word have been bleached away and now it's just a grammatical marker.

Comment: Thank you for your directness, but 'what' bleaches, and how quickly does it happen?  While it's getting bleached, how are we to recognize which meaning applies?  I'm still using wil to mean choose, as in 'free will,' 'willingness' and 'willful.'  Or has the word been derivationally morphed into more than one meaning?  And when that happens, doesn't it decrease word precision, forcing us to 'interpret' contextually, which often generates subjective misunderstanding?  I'm purusing more precise language...is my pursuit futile...one meaning for each word and only one word for each meaning?

Comment: @Christopher I would say yes, that pursuit is doomed to failure. Words are inherently imprecise—can you even nail down what "a single meaning" would mean?

Comment: math is able to do it, why can't words?  The problem is not the words, but the users. Computers rely on the precision of words, why can't we?  Using words for art and romance benefit from variety of meaning and mystery, and many cultures are built that way.  But when it comes to science and technology, precision matters.  Our brains also rely on precision for excellence, and while they can function adequately with less precision, the more concise and precise the better.  In summary, 'I' can't achieve greater precision alone, but we can...all of us together, if we choose...or 'will.'

Comment: @Christopher The key is that math and programming languages are trying to cover a relatively restricted domain. You can be perfectly precise and unambiguous with your meanings…as long as your meanings are, say, the natural numbers. But language needs to convey _everything_, and while it's not too hard to say whether a particular number is or is not zero, it's _much_ harder (and I would say impossible) to say whether a particular feeling is or is not "love".

Comment: I suspect we'll be encouraged to continue this exchange elsewhere, but in response, precision is on a spectrum, and the more precise the better.  For example, love is a function of value, whereby the more we value something, the 'more love we feel.'  There are many parts to feelings (how), but 'what' we are feeling is value, which can be measured and compared...and the more accurately we do that the better.  "Loving you to the moon and back" is romantic, but not very helpful when it comes to choosing a spouse, unless romance is preferred over effectiveness.  Precise can be boring...or better.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not just convey future. It can convey a number of things and is used in many ways.

Comment: @Lambie If you disagree, feel free to write another answer and explain.

Comment: Actually, not worth it since I think this is ELL and not linguistics.

Comment: > math is able to do it, why can't words?
// Math is, in fact, also highly context-dependent. Something as mundane as "f(x) = 0" could mean: (1) given the value of x, f(x) is zero; (2) given the function f, we define x such that f(x) is zero; (3) f is a function that maps every number x to zero.  There are possibly other meanings, and let's not even get started on the domain and range of the function f.

Comment: @jick i'm not talking about sentences, or propositions, I'm referring to the meaning of words.  f means function; = means equals; etc.  Context is required for all thought/communication, but the more precise the words/tools we use, including morphs and syntax, the better...if precision is valued enough.